# Drupal Text Block - Change on Per page basis

Tags: drupal-7, block, default, overriding

Is there a drupal block module that allows you to change the text of the block on a per page basis with the option of a default text for every page?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want different text in a block on a per page basis, one way to do this is to add a textarea field to the node for that page, and when block is rendered, look up the node for that page and pull the text from that field into that block.

It looks like this module does this for you:

https://www.drupal.org/project/cck_blocks

Here's a tutorial on how it works:

https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/cck-blocks/

Comment: **Thanks Nathan!** This is perfect. I Appreciate the help. Cheers